# Create and update progress bar using CFUserNotification API

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation

The following code creates and initialises a simple progress bar using CFUserNotification API. How would I add a callback to update the progress bar ? With this code, the progress is at the constant value indicated by prog.

```
float prog = 0.1;

CFNumberRef cfNum = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,kCFNumberFloatType, &prog);

const void* keys[] = { kCFUserNotificationAlertHeaderKey, kCFUserNotificationProgressIndicatorValueKey };

 const void* vals[] = { CFSTR("Progress Bar"), cfNum};

CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(0, keys, vals,
                sizeof(keys)/sizeof(*keys),
                &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
 
CFUserNotificationRef pDlg = NULL;

 pDlg = CFUserNotificationCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0,
                     kCFUserNotificationPlainAlertLevel,
                     &nRes, dict);
```